# my protocol and delegates not working?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

I have created a protocol to pass "itemInformation" to the other view controller thru delegate like  below:

```
 protocol ItemDataDelegate {

func ItemInformation(itemID:String,itemname:String,itemPrice:String)
}


class ItemTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var passItemID:String?
var PassItemName : String?
var PassAddon : String?
var PassItemPrice : String?

var Itemdelegate: ItemDataDelegate?


@IBOutlet var itemName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var itemPrice: UILabel!



override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code

}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state

}


@IBAction func OrderBtnPressed(sender: AnyObject) {


    print(PassItemName)
    print(PassAddon)
    print(passItemID)
    print(PassItemPrice)



        let itemnameInfo:String = PassItemName!
        let itempriceInfo:String = PassItemPrice!
        let itemID:String = passItemID!

        Itemdelegate?.ItemInformation(itemID,itemname:itemnameInfo as String, itemPrice: itempriceInfo as String)




}

}
```

Now here I am retrieving the protocol by implementing it below. for exapmle i am simply trying to print the pass value here but nothing happens.

```
class CustomAddOnVC:   UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate, ItemDataDelegate{

 var ItemTableViewCellObj:ItemTableViewCell? 

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

ItemTableViewCellObj?.Itemdelegate = self

}

  func ItemInformation(itemID: String, itemname: String, itemPrice: String) {
    print(itemID)
    print(itemname)
    print(itemPrice)
}
```

}
 Is there any mistake I am doing here?

Comment: In your CustomAddOnVC, set `Itemdelegate` to self. Eg: cellInstance. Itemdelegate = self

Comment: In CustomAddOnVC please write

Comment: damn naming conventions...

Answer (score 0):

In CustomAddOnVC please write

```
 ItemTableViewCellObj.Itemdelegate = self
```

in viewDidLoad or where ItemTableViewCell. in initialised . and also define  delegate with weak reference

```
weak var Itemdelegate: ItemDataDelegate?
```

replace this line in ItemTableViewCell OrderBtnPressed method

```
 Itemdelegate?.ItemInformation(itemID,itemname:itemnameInfo as String, itemPrice: itempriceInfo as String)
```

with this

```
self.itemDelegate?.itemInformation("itemID", itemname: "itemname", itemPrice: "itemPrice")
```

Comment: here what is  ItemTableViewCellObj??

Comment: You have CustomAddOnVC. And you use ItemTableViewCell here. Where do you initialize it?

Comment: i forget to set delegate for ItemDataDelegate in CustomAddOnVC class..  I am checking

Comment: Yes. that's what i want.

Comment: i have made some editing in my question in the 2nd part but still not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121238/discussion-between-smi-and-pradip-kumar).